# How to randomly draw something once in love2d

Tags: random, lua, random-seed, love2d

I'm currently trying to create brick breaker using love2d but the problem is whenever is used **math.random()** to generate random bricks the love application keeps running it multiple times and the brick moves constantly.

EDIT: So I want to generate bricks at particular column but the rows should be randomly selected. My basic idea was to do math.random(2) == 1 then drawing bricks using for loop but the problem is that it gets updated/drawn at every second and the bricks keeps on flickering/moving. I just want to randomly(only randomly select the y co-ordinate my x co-ordinate is fixed) to draw it once when you execute the code but its keep on flickering

The issue I'm facing - https://youtu.be/AJB5vH7yfHc

My code

```
    for y = 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT- 4, 10 do
        if math.random(2) == 1 then
            love.graphics.rectangle('line', VIRTUAL_WIDTH - 10, y, 5, 10)
        end
    end
```

Comment: If you're generating random bricks within the draw function then you're going to be generating them every time you draw a new frame. So if you're drawing 60 fps, then you're generating 60 new bricks every second. You might want some condition that you generate bricks inside. You're question is kind of confusing, I don't know quite what you're asking.

Comment: @Sam yeah exactly the problem is bricks are generating every 60s. I want to generate the brick once only when the application starts(generating randomly positioned bricks for different levels) hope it helps you. {In my code the bricks gets updated by dt}

Comment: "So I changed and I tried initializing a random variable in load function and in the draw function if the value equates then it draws the bricks" this is the way to do it but I dont think you have shown enough code to work out what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @MukeshIngham I updated the post, hoping I explained my problem better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after you edited the question, this sounds more like what you're talking about.  Just take out that #column loop, and set it to create cells on the last column.

**love.load()**

```
--VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT  = love .graphics .getDimensions()

block_pos  = {}  --  table to store block positions
rows, columns  = 30, 20  --  you decide how many

chance_of_block  = 33  --  % chance of placing a block

block_width  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_WIDTH /columns )
block_height  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_HEIGHT /rows )

col  = columns -1  --  don't loop through columns, just use final column

for  row = 0,  rows -1  do

    if love .math .random() *100 <= chance_of_block then
        local xpos  = col *block_width
        local ypos  = row *block_height

        block_pos[ #block_pos +1 ] = { x = xpos,  y = ypos }
    end  --  rand

end  --  #columns

r, g, b  = 0.5, 0.5, 0.0
love .graphics .setColor( r, g, b )
```

**love.draw()**

```
for b = 1, #block_pos do
    local block  = block_pos[b]

    love .graphics .rectangle( 'line',  block.x,  block.y,  block_width,  block_height )
end  --  #block_pos
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked. I wanted to draw brick of a particular size so I changed that in love.graphics.rectangle. People on this site are really very helpful

Answer (score 0):

**generate block positions in love.load()**

```
--VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT  = love .graphics .getDimensions( )

block_pos  = {}  --  table to store block positions
rows, columns  = 5, 8  --  you decide how many

chance_of_block  = 75  --  % chance of placing a block

block_width  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_WIDTH /columns )
block_height  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_HEIGHT /rows )

for  row = 0,  rows -1  do
    for  col = 0,  columns -1  do

        if love .math .random() *100 <= chance_of_block then
            local xpos  = col *block_width
            local ypos  = row *block_height

            local red   = love .math .random()
            local green = love .math .random()
            local blue  = love .math .random()

            block_pos[ #block_pos +1 ] = { x = xpos,  y = ypos,  r = red,  g = green,  b = blue }
        end  --  rand

    end  --  #columns
end  --  #rows
```

(edited: realized row & column should start from 0 index, so they line up on the screen)

---

**then draw them with love.draw()**

```
for b = 1, #block_pos do
    local block  = block_pos[b]

    love .graphics .setColor( block.r,  block.g,  block.b )
    love .graphics .rectangle( 'fill',  block.x,  block.y,  block_width,  block_height )
end  --  #block_pos
```

Comment: This selects the brick colour randomly but the positions aren't generated randomly I tried removing the RGB colour part. After that this code just draws the bricks at the same positions I tried it running multiple times and decreased the chance of generation

Comment: you must'a typo'd or your VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT are set wrong, 'cuz it works fine here.